# Usage of "won't" instead of "didn't" in particular way of communication

Tags: word-choice, differences, tenses

I'm a bit confused about the usage of the word "won't" in a specific situation. For example, I am communicating with a person and I want to tell the person that

> How much ever I tried, the image **didn't** show up on the screen.

1) Can it also be expressed as:

> How much ever I tried, the image **won't** show up on the screen.

2) If yes, in what way are they different?

3) And when to be used?

4) And which type of past tense are both sentences of?

Comment: [**Won't**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/won%27t) is a contraction of "will not" and why do you think it is used in the past tense? I've fixed some typos and please take a look.

Comment: /How ever much I tried/, not  /how much ever I tried/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both sentences are slightly different.

The first sentence expresses:

`all my attempts have failed.`

And second sentence expresses:

`whatever I am doing right now is futile. All my ongoing efforts are useless.` Although with a hint of the past tense.

So answer to your question 1 is NO.

As I have stated above, sentence 1 can be used when you have exhausted all your options and are stating this. Sentence 2 is used when you are in the process of exhausting all your options.

And by options I mean `How much ever I tried...`

Comment: Hope it helps!!

Comment: Before downvoting, please state why you are downvoting...

Comment: "The boy tried to wake up his sister and she would not wake up". This I read in newspaper and came across such use of "would not" for first time and got confused. Yes, "wont" was not the right word, the way I wanted to frame my question. Thank you so much for clearing my query.

Comment: Welcome! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

As won't is the contraction of will not (implying future time) and didn't is the contraction form of did not (implying past time), the difference in these two statements is a question of **WHEN** you say this.  The first statement with didn't could be said describing a past event to a friend or colleagues.  The second implies that you are still having problems resolving the issue and you are trying to talk to someone who is helping you, such as a person who works on a help desk.

Answer (score 0):

**Didn't** is the literal and correct formal usage.

**Won't** is a metaphor. You are implying that the *image* could choose. Shall I, shan't I show up on the screen. And you are having a battle of wills with the image. This is an example of the Pathetic fallacy: it's fine to say 'Won't' - it adds a human dimension to your writing.

> Pathetic fallacy is a literary device wherein the author attributes
>   human emotions and traits to nature or inanimate objects. For example,
>   the following descriptions refer to weather and how it affects the
>   mood, which can add atmosphere to a story: smiling skies, somber
>   clouds, angry storm, or bitter winter.7 Jul 2015
>   [iterary devices.net](http://literarydevices.net/pathetic-fallacy/)